# Multiple farms, one Newsfeed?

Tags: 2013, newsfeed, distributedcache

There a multiple service application I can share between farms:

- Busiess Data Connectivity
- Machine Translation
- Managed Metadata
- User Profile
- Search
- Secure Store

What happens when I want to share the Newsfeed (SharePoint 2013) with multiple farms, i.e. only have one MySite/Newsfeed for all farms?

I can share the user profile service application no problem - what about the MySite? Would I just redirect to the URL of the first farm or do both farms have the same MySite host anyways?

Some of the newsfeed data is available through the distributed cache service, is it possible to consume one distributed cache service farm with multiple SharePoint farms? Also what about all the other data within the SharePoint database (e.g. comments or posts to the all company feed), is that shared as well?

Basically: Can I share one Newsfeed/MySite with multiple farms?